# Android - Slidr plugin weird margin when closing activity on slide down

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I'm using this plugin:

https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr

When I slide down to close the activity there is a weird margin above the activity while I'm sliding down:

[image]

Inside activity:

```
val config = SlidrConfig.Builder()
    .position(SlidrPosition.TOP)
    .build();

Slidr.attach(this, config)
```

Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
```

and the style:

```
<style name="slider" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">56dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` to Theme style solves the problem